# Text not appearing in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to display the score for a game I am making but for some reason the text won't appear once added to the group.

Here is my code:

```
Text scoreText = new Text(scoreString);

scoreText.setFont(new Font("ARIAL", 30);
scoreText.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
scoreText.setFill(Color.WHITE);

Pane scorePane = new Pane(scoreText);

scoreText.relocate(100, 100);

root.getChildren().add(scoreText);
```

Comment: Doesn't this give you an exception?

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` in this line `scoreText.setFont(new Font("ARIAL", 30);`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add `scoreText` to two different parents: once here:

```
Pane scorePane = new Pane(scoreText);
```

which makes `scoreText` a child of `scorePane`, and once more here:

```
root.getChildren().add(scoreText);
```

which makes `scoreText` a child of `root`. Since a node cannot appear twice in the scene graph, this just won't work.

If you want `scoreText` to be wrapped in a pane, add it to the pane and add the pane to `root`:

```
Text scoreText = new Text(scoreString);

// ...

Pane scorePane = new Pane(scoreText);

scoreText.relocate(100, 100);

root.getChildren().add(scorePane);
```

If you don't need it in the pane, then just add it directly to `root`:

```
Text scoreText = new Text(scoreString);

// ...

// omit this:
// Pane scorePane = new Pane(scoreText);

scoreText.relocate(100, 100);

root.getChildren().add(scoreText);
```